# Twilio: Accessing IBM Watson Speech-to-text results payload

Tags: php, twilio, ibm-watson, twilio-php

New Twilio developer here. My app uses the IBM Watson Speech-to-text Add-on, but I'm having trouble accessing the results payload in my callback. I can't find helpful documentation or any discussion of the issue in forums.

**What I know/What I've tried**

- The payload resource exists – I'm able to access it directly via browser.
- Using the syntax prescribed by the Twilio PHP helper library client returns a [61005](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/61005) "Bad request" error:

  ```
      $request = $client->v1->lookups
                 ->phoneNumbers("+1XXXXXXXXXX")
                 ->fetch(
                         array(
                               "AddOns" => "ibm_watson_speechtotext",
                         ));
  ```
- Using cURL to get the resource directly has been equally unfruitful, returning an empty string.

  ```
      $request = json_decode($_REQUEST['AddOns']);
      error_log("URL: ".$request->results->ibm_watson_speechtotext->payload[0]->url);
      $ch = curl_init($request->results->ibm_watson_speechtotext->payload[0]->url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account_sid:$token");
      $json = curl_exec($ch);
      if($json === false) {
          error_log("cURL error: ".curl_error($ch));
          error_log(print_r($json,true));
      }
      curl_close($ch);
      $obj = json_decode($json);
  ```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resources should help you find the results you're looking for.

Your first code snippet above doesn't apply (Lookup is a different product).
instead you will want to use the add-on results api to grab the results.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/add-ons/results-api

For your second snippet, you will need to enable follow redirect option with CURL.

> Clients will need to follow the redirect to receive the data
>   associated with a Payload resource.

These may also help as you explore add-ons:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/add-ons/using-add-ons#add-on-results-available-callback
and
https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/voice/how-to-use-recordings-add-ons-in-python

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. The Lookup attempt seemed really strange to me; I was grasping for solutions and overgeneralized one of the examples in the Add-on documentation. I do wish there were a workable API solution to this issue...